# Sqoop java api stringInput parameters

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I want use Sqoop Java API for export content of SequenceFile to Oracle.
Where I can see parameters for form.getInputString()  methods?
All examples at www represents a command line commands, Apache Sqoop documentation not contains necessary information.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have managed to compile some example code http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.5/ClientAPI.html  but when I execute them, I receive error complaining about "linkConfig" does not exist. The thing is that I have also found other examples where the string is different, what kind of suggests that it is user defined. But how does it work to make the mapping with the library so that the values can be effectively used?